# There is problem in my linked list. The program cannot read other position, it only read position 1

Tags: c, hyperlink

The problem with my code is that it cannot read the linked list when I want to update the info of position 2 or 3 and so on. It only reads position 1. Here is my code.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Student{
    int studno; // student number
    char name[20]; // Student name
    float per; // GWA
    struct Student *next; // next student
}Student;

Student *head;

int count(Student *h);
void create(Student *h); // Add Student info
void deleteByPos(Student *h); // Delete Student info
void updateByPos(Student *h); // Edit Student info
void searchByPos(Student *h);// Search student on the list
void display(Student *h); // View all student's info
void printline();

int main(){
    int ch;
    do {
        system("cls");
        printline();
        printf("\t   STUDENT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM\n");
        printline();
        printf("1. ADD LIST\n");
        printf("2. DELETE LIST\n");
        printf("3. EDIT BY POSITION\n");
        printf("4. SEARCH BY POSITION\n");
        printf("5. VIEW ALL\n");
        printf("0. EXIT\n");
         printline();
        printf("Enter you choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        switch(ch){
            case 1: create(head);
                    break;
            case 2: deleteByPos(head);
                    break;
            case 3: updateByPos(head);
                    break;
            case 4: searchByPos(head);
                    break;
            case 5: display(head);
                    break;
            case 0: printf("Thank you \nHave a Nice Day!");
                    break;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        system("pause");
    }while(ch !=0);
}

void create(Student *h){
    int studno;
    char name[20];
    float per;
    printline();
    printf("Enter Student Number : ");
    scanf("%d", &studno);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter Student Name : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &name);
    printf("Enter Student GWA : ");
    scanf("%f", &per);
    if(h==NULL){
        head = (Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student));
        head -> studno = studno;
        head -> per = per;
        strcpy(head -> name,name);
        head -> next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        while(h->next != NULL)
            h = h-> next;
            h-> next =(Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student));
            h-> next -> studno = studno;
            strcpy(h-> next ->name, name);
             h-> next -> per = per;
            h-> next -> next = NULL;
    }
}
int count(Student *h){
    int cnt=0;
    while (h != NULL){
      h = h ->next;
      cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

void deleteByPos(Student *h){
    int n = count(h);
    int pos, i;
    Student *tmp;
    printf("Enter Position to Delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    if(pos>n){
        printf("\nINDEX OUT OF BOUNDS");
    }else if(pos==1){ // To delete from first position
        tmp = h;
        head = h->next;
        free(tmp);
        printf("\nRECORD SUCCESSFULLY DELETED");
    } else if (pos>0){
        for (i=1; 1<pos-1; i++)
            h = h ->next;
        tmp = h -> next;
        h -> next = h -> next -> next;
        free(tmp);
         printf("\nRECORD SUCCESSFULLY DELETED");
    }
}

void updateByPos(Student *h){
    int n = count(h);
    int pos, i;
    printf("Enter Position to Edit: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    if(pos>n){
        printf("\nINDEX OUT OF BOUNDS");
    }else if(pos>0){
        char name[20];

        for(i=1; 1<pos;i++)
           h = h -> next;
            printline();
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Enter New Name: ");
            scanf("%[^\n]s",h->name);
            printf("Record Updated Successfully");
    }
}

void searchByPos(Student *h){
    int n = count(h);
    int pos, i;
    printf("Enter Position to Search: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    if(pos>n){
        printf("\nINDEX OUT OF BOUNDS");
    }else if(pos>0){
        for(i=1; 1<pos;i++)
            h= h -> next;
            printline();
            printf("\t STUDENT RECORD FOUND \n");
            printline();
            printf("%-10d%-20s%f\n", h->studno, h->name, h->per);
            printline();
    }
}

void display(Student *h){
    printline();
    printf("%-10s%-20s%s\n", "Stud No.", " Name", "Percentage");
     printline();
    while(h != NULL){
        printf("%-10d%-20s%.2f\n", h->studno, h->name, h->per);
        h = h ->next;
    }
     printline();
}

void printline(){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<50; i++)
        printf("-");
        printf("\n");
}
```

For example:

Let us say, The user inputs 4 students

---

```
       STUDENT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM
```

---

1. ADD LIST
2. DELETE LIST
3. EDIT BY POSITION
4. SEARCH BY POSITION
5. VIEW ALL
6. EXIT

---

Enter your choice:
5

```
--------------------------------------------------
Stud No.   Name               Percentage
--------------------------------------------------
1         lisa                97.00
2         jisoo               98.00
3         jennie              99.00
4         rose                100.00
--------------------------------------------------
```

Press any key to continue . . .

The user wants to edit position 2

it becomes like this, the program should ask "Enter New Name:" and print "Record Updated Successfully"

```
--------------------------------------------------
           STUDENT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM
--------------------------------------------------
1. ADD LIST
2. DELETE LIST
3. EDIT BY POSITION
4. SEARCH BY POSITION
5. VIEW ALL
0. EXIT
--------------------------------------------------
Enter you choice: 3
Enter Position to Edit: 2

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 82.339 s
Press any key to continue.
```

It is the same problem in search function. I don't have a problem with other functions aside from the update and search functions. How to fix this?

Comment: You should tag this windows.  cls is windows specific. Your code is incomplete so we cannot run it. Please minimize to demonstrate one problem (see [mre]).

Comment: It's a good idea to separate the UI (prompts) from the business logic.   You could for example ask for the position in main() then pass it into searchByPos().

Comment: Even though you only need help with two functions, it would help if you can post the missing functions (e.g. `printline/create/deleteByPos/display`) so we can download, compile, and run your program. Also, to post the sample input data. I'm guessing that it's not too much more code, so I'd edit your question and post your entire program as a single code block. Although the problem is probably in what you already posted, there is always the possibility that one of the issues is in what you didn't post.

Comment: @CraigEstey I already posted the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo `1` instead of `i` in your loop condition (both in `updateByPos()` and `searchByPos()`).  I also moved the `int i` declaration into the loop:

```
        for(int i=1; i<pos; i++)
            h = h->next;
```

If you move the UI functionality, say, to `main()` then you could reuse the `searchByPos()` in `deletebyPos()` and `updateByPos()` instead of duplicating essentially the same code.  Also consider make `Student *head` a local variable in `main()` instead of a global variable.  Your code already does the right thing by passing it around.